# Create a special shape using css

Tags: css

Is this shape possible with pure css and only using 1 div?

[shape](http://static.wixstatic.com/media/41d000_17f06ebbb6d3e6b7b83788f3e873d0f1.png_srz_275_71_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_png_srz)

Comment: Research first, then ask question about specific implementation.

Comment: yes i tried, and i found that i can use "border" to make the shape go in, but then i cannot make it round .. so its like: either round borders OR screwed border on right side which is the desired result.
i ALWAYS research before posting a question.

Comment: -1: Link-Rot again. Please take the time to include a sample inline your question. 90% of StackOverflow would be worthless already if everyone did just dump URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I would love to see your tries, even if they were not correct.

Here is how i do it, create only one element like this:

```
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Everything is done with css to make this shape. First, the top rounded corners are made with:

```
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
```

The angle border at right is made with the css selector `:after` using transparent border like this:

```
border-bottom: 76px solid #333;
border-right: 40px solid transparent;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8h2yA/) is the jsfiddle!

Comment: thanks, this is the closest thing i could come to making that shape http://jsfiddle.net/r6V7f/1/

Answer (score 3):

[Yes](http://www.css3shapes.com/). This shape is most certainly possible.

Comment: yes i can see that almost everything is possible, i just dont know how to combine transparent borders with round borders. please read my comment on above thank you.